# Javascript: How to initialize a 2 dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I thought initializing an multi dimensional array would be easy:

```
row = Array(4).fill(0)
block = Array(4).fill(row)
block[2][2] = 15
```

but that just creates an array of one row, 4 times, so if I assign block[2][2] = 15, then the whole column is 15.

```
(4) [Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4)]
0:(4) [0, 0, 15, 0]
1:(4) [0, 0, 15, 0]
2:(4) [0, 0, 15, 0]
3:(4) [0, 0, 15, 0]
```

I tried `Array(4).fill(Array(4).fill(0))` but had the same result.

Comment: JavaScript is pass by reference, not value. So when you fill the `block` array with `row`, you're assigning the same object to every index.

Comment: got it, same row, 4 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a helper function to initialize your two dimensional array. For example:

```js
const grid = (r, c) => Array(r).fill(null).map(r => Array(c).fill(null));

const g = grid(4, 4);
g[2][2] = 15;

console.log(g);
```

Comment: that works good. Seems harder than it s/b, but I'll take it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was actually quite challenging to solve. I much prefer the accepted answer from fubar - however I thought I would add another possibility for some variance.

**Pro:** Doesn't obfuscate that you are dealing with an Array (like with the accepted answer).

**Con:** Hard to read.

```js
var row = new Array(4).fill(0)
var block = new Array(4).fill(0).map(v => deepClone(row))
block[2][2] = 15
console.log(block);

function deepClone(array){return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));}
```

How does this work? Well after you fill the array with blank values, `.map` is now able to iterate each and replace the value. In this case, it is a hacky deep clone of row thanks to the trusty ole `JSON.parse`.

Comment: This will only work with native objects and primitives. If you use a self defined class, it'll lose it's type.